# garbage collection for javascript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

I have two piece of code
sample 1

```
(function(){

var x = 1;

 this.getx = function() { return x; };

})();
```

---

sample 2

```
(function(){

var x = 1;

 this.getx = function() { };

})();
```

---

both code samples create a closure, x in sample one is referenced, while x in sample two is not referenced, I know x in sample one will not be garbage collected,  my question will x in sample two be garbage collected?

Comment: "x in sample one is not referenced" - Maybe you got samples 1 and 2 switched around?

Comment: In sample 1 activation record containing x will likely live as long as the function since the function references it. A JavaScript engine might realize x cannot be modified and realize that x could be treated as a constant but that is unlikely but the example could be rewritten with a this.setx to make it more clear that x will need to stay around.

Answer (score 1):

The ECMAScript standard is intentionally silent on how the garbage collector should work so implementations are likely to differ. However, in general, if an object is not referencible from a live object it will be collected.

In sample 2 it means that the closure will likely be collected but it is also likely a closure will not even be created since the function does not reference it. Closures are expensive and modern JavaScript engines try to avoid creating them unless they are forced to.

Comment: is this specification of of ECMAScript that construct like sample 2 will not create a closure? I just want to understand how the gc works, so that I know how to write my code better.

Comment: No. The standard only specifies observable effects, but since it is clear from the code that one is not necessary it is likely one will not be created.

Comment: is there any profiler to see how engine allocate and collection memory in js engine?

Comment: Chrome appears to have one in their developer tools called "Heap Snapshot". I haven't used it so I cannot say whether it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection in Javascript is a nebulous thing.  Generally speaking, you can assume (though we know what assuming does) that once there are no references to a variable (eg, once it goes out of scope), it will be garbage collected.  However, your closures will not work as you intend because they are not assigned to anything; thus you will have no function object to call `getx()` on.  If you were to assign it, though, `x` would never be out of scope unless you used the `delete` keyword on any variables holding the function reference.

Simple rule: use the `delete` operator whenever you're concerned about collection - this will remove the reference, and it's more likely that the memory will be freed.

Edit: comments by @chuckj aside, whether you use `delete` or assign the variable to `undefined` still lends to the point that you want to get the reference count to 0 if there's to be any hope of freeing the memory.

Comment: Using delete in this fashion is really bad advice. In modern engines this will likely cause a type transition which could be very expensive. It is better just set the variable to undefined.

Comment: Any reference to support that?

Comment: Any talk by Lars Bak on the architecture of V8 should be sufficient. In general, don't use delete on an object unless it is really being used as a hashtable. Doing so will likely cause the object be converted to an inefficient representation.

Answer (score 0):

To modern browsers, x in sample two will be garbage collected in most browsers, except for ie6